# Mouse event program freezes my Blender

Tags: python, opengl

recently I am trying this code for handling some clicks, mixed by `bpy` and `bgl`. However when I "Run script", then select it from the menu, when I clikc, the Blender freezes. I have to close it.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_ray_tri
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_vector_3d, region_2d_to_location_3d, region_2d_to_origin_3d

import bgl #GL module


class GLUtils(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def getViewport():
        view = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_INT, 4)
        bgl.glGetIntegerv(bgl.GL_VIEWPORT, view)
        return view

    @staticmethod
    def getProjectionMTX():
        proj_mtx = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_DOUBLE, [4,4])
        bgl.glGetDoublev(bgl.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj_mtx)
        return  proj_mtx

    @staticmethod
    def getModelViewMTX():
        mv_mtx = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_DOUBLE, [4, 4])
        bgl.glGetDoublev(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mv_mtx)
        return  mv_mtx


    @staticmethod
    def mouseCoordsTo3DView(mx, my):
        depth = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_FLOAT, [0.0])
        bgl.glReadPixels(mx, my, 1, 1, bgl.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, bgl.GL_FLOAT, depth)
        # if (depth[0] != 1.0):
        world_x = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_DOUBLE, 1, [0.0])
        world_y = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_DOUBLE, 1, [0.0])
        world_z = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_DOUBLE, 1, [0.0])
        view1 = GLUtils.getViewport()
        model = GLUtils.getModelViewMTX()
        proj = GLUtils.getModelViewMTX()
        bgl.gluUnProject(mx, my, depth[0],
                         model, proj,
                         view1,
                         world_x, world_y, world_z)
        return world_x[0], world_y[0], world_z[0]


class MouseToCollision(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.mouse_collision"
    bl_label = "MouseTo3D"

    region_x = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    region_y = bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialize")

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Clicked!")
        print(GLUtils.mouseCoordsTo3DView(self.region_x, self.region_y))

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':  # Apply
            self.region_x = event.mouse_region_x
            self.region_y = event.mouse_region_y
            self.execute(context)
        elif event.type == 'RIGHTMOUSE':  # Cancel
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.execute(context)

        print(context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self))
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MouseToCollision)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MouseToCollision)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

# bpy.ops.wm.mouse_collision('EXEC_DEFAULT')
```

Maybe I messed my operator or I am misusing it.

Comment: Suggest a look at the modal timer operator template where `return {'PASS_THROUGH'}` is used, thus allowing user to interact with UI while operator is running modal.  Simply returning `'PASS_THROUGH'` from your  `MouseToCollision.modal` method unlocks UI.  For other modal operators it is desirable to "lock" the UI until that operation is completed or cancelled.

Comment: PS would still recommend using a timer set up.

Comment: Thanks, any simple example of that?

Comment: Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Modal Timer

Comment: Actually, the output is visible when I run Blender under terminal. No idea that it's shell showed nothing.